# GWT Designer needs to refresh at each change of a contrl

Tags: gwt, gwt-designer

I am using GWT designer but I am getting a problem with it, everytime, I have to refresh because as soon as I change a control, the form in designer mode becomes like this

[image]

As you see, I cannot see anything until I refresh, the focus control is label but I cannot see it.

Does somebody knows what the problem is?